# Can't import Python module on path (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, import, pythonpath

I have `C:\\Users\\...\\some_folder` on my `PYTHONPATH`, which contains a file called `__init__.py`. Now, I have another Python file in a different folder and when, in this other file, I try to import the module `some_folder` corresponds to, it can't find it.

If I'm correct, placing a directory with an `__init__.py` in it on my `PYTHONPATH` should be the guaranteed way of making every other Python file be able to see it. So, why wouldn't it be able to? Is there any way a directory on the `PYTHONPATH` isn't visible to other Python files?

Comment: No, it's not the package directory but its parent directory that gets added to `sys.path`. Typically that's done via `PYTHONPATH` but you can also add a .pth file to the site-packages directory.

Comment: @eryksun So instead I should add whatever directory is directly above the one I want (its `..`, effectively)? Cos I have that on the path as well.

Comment: It can get confusing if both a directory and its parent are on the path.  If the directory foo contains bar.py then you can import it both as bar and as foo.bar.  The class imported from foo will not be equivalent to the class imported from foo.bar.